# Is there a way to return the rest of a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to return the rest of an array in JavaScript i.e the portion of the array that consists of all elements but the first element of the array?

Note: I do not ask for returning a new array e.g. with `arr.slice(1)` etc. and I do not want to chop off the first element of the array e.g. with `arr.shift()`.

For example, given the array `[3, 5, 8]` the rest of the array is `[5, 8]` and if the rest of the array is changed, e.g. by an assignment (a destructive operation), the array also changes. I just figured out that as a test that proves the rest is the rest of the array but not a new array consists of the rest of the elements of the array.

Note: The following code example is to describe what I want, but not specifically what I want to do (i.e. not the operations I want to perform). What I want to do is in the `every` algorithm at the bottom.

```
var arr = [3, 5, 8];
var rest = rest(arr); // rest is [5, 8]
rest.push(13); // rest is [5, 8, 13] and hence the arr is [3, 5, 8, 13]
```

An example I possibly need this and I would want to have it is following algorithm and many other I am writing in that [GitHub organization](https://github.com/tower-of-babel), in both of which I use always `arr.slice(1)`:

```
function every(lst, f) {
    if (lst.length === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (f(lst[0]) === true) {
            return every(lst.slice(1), f);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think having what I ask for instead of `arr.slice(1)` would keep the memory usage of such algorithms and retain the recursive-functional style I want to employ.

Comment: You ***can not*** create a pointer to a subarray in JavaScript

Comment: That is not possible. There has to be two different arrays. You can create a custom push function which push elements to both the arrays.

Comment: What is the real issue you're trying to solve? Because this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: _"rest is [5, 8, 13] and hence the arr is [3, 5, 8, 13]"_ doesn't make sense. Why the intermediate step of grabbing the last elements of an array. All you're doing is pushing a new element to an array. What purpose does that step have?

Comment: @Andy imagine if you could create a "view" onto an array, something that looks like an array but really shares storage with some segment of another array.

Comment: I'll extend my answer with some sample code for typed arrays.

Comment: @Andy I think my purpose should not be in hard question, yet I understand, you may show me if I am in a unnecessary direction. But I think I am not. The demonstration of the arr in the code comments does not imply that I want to reach a final state of the array `arr`. I will try to give an algorithm implementation to show why I need it. The main reason to preserve memory space.

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh So far you seem right by your **can not** comment

Comment: @Selçuk If you only need this for internal implementation of an algorithm, not as a result value to pass around anywhere, just do some magic with indexing the when accessing the array. I'm looking forward to the code of your use case :)

Comment: Right; providing a good answer would be much easier if you would describe a more realistic problem you're trying to solve. The sample code you gave is useful as a simple illustration, but you're asking for an unusual feature so some larger context would help people provide idiomatic approaches.

Comment: @Bergi @Pointy Actually I have many examples in that [GitHub organization](https://github.com/tower-of-babel) I work on readily. I currently do an `arr.slice(1)` but I want to avoid the allocating a new array copy to be more memory efficient while still retaining my recursive, functional style. I will put one example in my question and the link of the repo here and maybe in question

Comment: I updated my answer. Thank you for the additional context.

Comment: @Pointy you are welcome

Comment: @Pointy @Bergi @Ovenwand et all, Is that true what I ask for the rest of an array would be more memory efficient than using the `arr.slice(1)` instead? `arr.slice(1)` returns a new array. By the way, et all could be a cool mention feature.

Comment: your function returns always `false`, because every sliced array goes up to zero elements and in this case `false` is returned. i suggest to change the first check to return a `true` value, like in [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which returns `true` for empty arrays.

Comment: @Selçuk I think creating a "view" on the array would be more efficient than creating a new array with copies of values from the original, but your algorithm would still be creating *something* on each recursive call; it would be best to avoid creating anything at all, which is what the code in my updated answer does.

Comment: @Pointy What are the things other than the new slice of the array my algorithm creates on each recursive call? I need to know at least an overview to that to know what resources I use.

Comment: Well if you were to create some kind of proxy, the proxy itself would be an object, even if it were a small, simple one. A new object would therefore be created on each recursive call. It would not be very expensive, but it would be more expensive than not creating anything.

Comment: I mean in current version

Answer (score 1):

No, this is generally not possible. There are no "views on" or "pointers to" normal arrays<sup>1</sup>.

You might use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to fake it, but I doubt this is a good idea.

<sub>1: It's trivial to do this on [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) (which are views on a backing buffer), but notice that you cannot `push` to them.</sub>

---

> I possibly need this and I would want to have it for recursive-functional style algorithms where I currently use `arr.slice(1)` but would prefer to keep memory usage low

Actually, all of these implementations do have low memory usage - they don't allocate more memory than the input. Repeatedly calling `slice(1)` does lead to high pressure on the garbage collector, though.

If you were looking for better efficiency, I would recommend to

- avoid recursion. JS engines still didn't implement tail recursion, so recursion isn't cheap.
- not to pass around (new copies of) arrays. Simply pass around an index at which to start, e.g. by using an inner recursive function that closes over the array parameter and accesses `array[i]` instead of `array[0]`. See @Pointy's updated answer for an example.

If you were looking for a more functional style, I would recommend to use [folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). (Also known as [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in JavaScript, although you might need to roll your own if you want laziness). Implement your algorithms in terms of `fold`, then it's easy to swap out the `fold` implementation for a more efficient (e.g. iterative) one.

Last but not least, for higher efficiency while keeping a recursive style you can use [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). Their interface might not look especially functional, but if you insist you could easily create an immutable wrapper that lazily produces a linked list.

Comment: I'm not sure why one would want what the OP asked but I think a Proxy would do the trick if it were really necessary (and not something misguided).

Comment: @Pointy That's exactly why I haven't posted code for the proxy yet :-)

Comment: Also it occurs to me that using a Proxy might defeat an original goal of efficiency, depending on how it's used.

Comment: @Pointy it's worth keeping in mind that the hit on efficiency might be entirely a non-factor. Premature optimisation and all.

Comment: @vlaz sure, but my point is that the same caveat might apply to the OP itself :)

Comment: @Bergi Can you supply more context and leads to pages where I can read about `folds`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code posted in the update to the question, it's clear why you might want to be able to "alias" a portion of an array. Here is an alternative that is more typical of how I would solve the (correctly) perceived efficiency problem with your implementation:

```
function every(lst, f) {
    function r(index) {
      if (index >= lst.length)
        return true; // different from OP, but I think correct

      return f(lst[index]) && r(index+1);
    }
    return r(0);
}
```

That is still a recursive solution to the problem, but no array copy is made; the array is not changed at all. The general pattern is common even in more characteristically functional programming languages (Erlang comes to mind personally): the "public" API for some recursive code is augmented by an "internal" or "private" API that provides some extra tools for keeping track of the progress of the recursion.

---

*original answer*

You're looking for [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var first = arr.shift();
console.log(first); // 1
console.log(arr); // [2, 3]
```

This is a *linear time* operation: the execution cost is relative to the length of the original array. For most small arrays that does not really matter much, but if you're doing lots of such work on large arrays you may want to explore a better data structure.

Note that with ordinary arrays it is not possible to create a new "shadow" array that overlaps another array. You can do something like that with typed arrays, but for general purpose use in most code typed arrays are somewhat awkward.

The first limitation of typed arrays is that they are, of course, *typed*, which means that the array "view" onto the backing storage buffer gives you values of only one consistent type. The second limitation is that the only available types are numeric types: integers and floating-point numbers of various "physical" (storage) sizes. The third limitation is that the size of a typed array is fixed; you can't extend the array without creating a new backing buffer and copying.

Such limitations would be quite familiar to a FORTRAN programmer of course.

So to create an array for holding 5 32-bit integers, you'd write

```
var ints = new Int32Array(5);
```

You can put values into the array just like you put values into an ordinary array, so long as you get the type right (well close enough):

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  ints[i] = i;
console.log(ints); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now: to do what the OP asked, you'd grab the buffer from the array we just created, and then make a new typed array on top of the same buffer at an offset from the start. The offsets when doing this are always in bytes, regardless of the type used to create the original array. That's super useful for things like looking at the individual parts of a floating point value, and other "bit-banging" sorts of jobs, though of course that doesn't come up much in normal JavaScript coding. Anyway, to get something like the `rest` array from the original question:

```
var rest = new Int32Array(ints.buffer, 4);
```

In that statement, the "4" means that the new array will be a view into the buffer starting 4 bytes from the beginning; 32-bit integers being 4 bytes long, that means that the new view will skip the first element of the original array.

Comment: Well this is not what op asked `rest is [5, 8, 13] and hence the arr is [3, 5, 8, 13]`. ??

Comment: @CodeManiac the OP's question is self-contradictory. He says he does not want a new array to be created; otherwise clearly `.slice()` would be the answer.

Comment: I am updating the question to specify not to remove the first element from the array. Oh! Actually I had done that originally. Thanks @CodeManiac. I have realized that seeing your comment

Comment: @Selçuk in that case  the answer is "you cannot do that."

Comment: @Pointy just out of curiosity i want to know is there any workaround to achieve this ?  because as far as i know it's not possible to have a subarray reference in js

Comment: @Pointy To be specific, is there a way? So you could mean the answer would be "No, there is not" ;)

Comment: @CodeManiac mee too

Comment: As I wrote in my answer as an edit, you can do that with typed arrays, but typed arrays are not as easy to use (by far) as ordinary JavaScript arrays.

Comment: @vlaz what part do you need more clarification.

Comment: @CodeManiac check the edit to my answer. Typed arrays are like "views" into a backing buffer. They are somewhat cumbersome to use of course compared to plain old JavaScript arrays. Whether it would be worth the awkwardness would of course depend on the application, which in this case we don't know.

Comment: @Selçuk it would be helpful if you could provide an example from some other programming environment where creating something like what you're asking is possible.

Comment: @Pointy thanks will check them out for sure. as i am in learning stage so curious to learn new thing. thanks mate. following your answers from quite a long time :) i guess you can post one example here if you don't mind posting that will be helpful and valid answer too

Comment: @Pointy What is the self-contradiction you have spotted in my question?

Comment: @Selçuk that comment was made before I completely understood what you were asking. What you want to do is not a common thing to do in JavaScript programming, so it's not something that I would think of doing myself or assume someone else would want to do.

Comment: @Pointy I see. I did not know the instant of comment. Yes, it is not a common think to do in JavaScript and may not be possible straightforwardly.

Comment: @Pointy Do you mean creating this in another programming language, or a working code example that I use or need to use this?

Comment: @Selçuk well it's interesting to me for the very reason that I would not consider even thinking of it when solving problems with JavaScript. You had this curiosity so anything about how the question popped into your head would be helpful :)

Comment: @Pointy I have added one algorithm I use this and a link to the repos. I have tried to ake my point why I think I need it in an update to my question. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: @Selçuk well it's not a *general* answer but I will add a suggestion based on the code you added to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript can't do this, the only real solution to your problem is [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly). Otherwise use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: "Note: I do not ask for returning a new array e.g. with `arr.slice(1)`" - from the question

Comment: @vlaz I expanded my answer. My bad.

Comment: Using a Proxy is a really good idea; that in fact might be the best answer.

Comment: I think `rest(arr).push()` do not modify the origin array as OP want.

Comment: @appleapple No, it does. Since the rest(arr) I want is not just a copy of the value of the rest of the array.

Comment: @Selçuk the `.slice()` part of the answer is "wrong" but the suggestion to use a Proxy is not.

Comment: @Selçuk sorry I may not be clear, I mean `rest(arr).push()` do not (modify the origin array as OP want.)

Comment: @appleapple I think I get it now, `rest(arr).push(13)` does not modify the original array, contrary to what I want, which is to modify it by that. I see.

Comment: @Selçuk why do you feel the need to create a pointer? JavaScript has its limitations, try thinking in solutions instead of problems.

Comment: @Selçuk fyi, you haven't provided us with any context and you're asking for something that isn't technically possible as many people on here mentioned.

Comment: @Ovenwand in part I have tried the reason in my question update. It can be useful to necessary thing, as well

Comment: @Ovenwand I have provided the context more than enough, you need to check the updates.
Yet people kept discussing on it, which I find useful, and I am trying to answer their questions. And my very question asks the technical availability of it, so, how can I know before asking other that already knowing it at first. In taht sense I find your last remark not sensible. No offense.

Comment: @Selçuk I figured it was a performance issue. I fear there is only one true solution to your problem, and that's WebAssembly.

Comment: @Ovenwand really. How?

Comment: @Selçuk Uhm, honestly, I haven't used it yet. However WebAssembly allows you to run C languages in the browser.

Comment: @Ovenwand I know about WebAssembly, it is a compilation target for web, code in any language provided a designed compiler for this can be compiled to it to run on web. But this would be about performance gain only I need to retain the code style I mention, too. Otherwise, I could use a for loop too.

Comment: @Selçuk well, can't you somehow extend the Array.prototype with a function written in webassembly? You could end up with `arr.rest(1).push(13)` syntax, right? I wish I had more knowledge on the subject..

Comment: @Ovenwand if possible, I mean writing in webassembly, or compiling to it also works for me although I prefer a direct solution, that is a good idea too. I would prefer to write a function instead of adding to `Array.prototype`. Anyways in my subject context as in question, I can go on using `arr.slice(1)` since it is perfectly correct in its own right.

Comment: Let me know when you find a solution. I'm gonna look into this tonight, I've become fascinated with your problem. I've also been thinking about some scary Proxy magic. Are you allowed to open a chat with me? My reputation is ****.

Answer (score 0):

please test this function

```
function rest(arr) {
  var a = arr.slice(1);
  a.push = function() {
    for (var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
      this[this.length] = arguments[i];
      arr[this.length] = arguments[i];
    }
    return this.length;
  };
  return a;
}
```